# Problems with SSH

Tags: ssh, rsa, ssh-keygen

I'm having issues with one of my computers on my server accepting my key. I've used this key on other computers I've set up before with no problems, I can SSH using it into many different servers.

Here's the tail of the log:

> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/james/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/james/.ssh/id_dsa
>
> debug1: Trying private key: /home/james/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>
> debug1: Next authentication method: password

My permissions are all correct, I've double checked them like 8 times now on both computers.  I've also tried deleting the auth hosts file from the server, that didn't seem to have an effect either. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant sshd log on the server?  The log file will depend on which distro you're using, e.g., /var/log/auth.log or maybe /var/log/secure.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the key is transferred correctly ?

Comment: Look at the debug log on the _server_. That's where the useful information will be.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing the private key file on the client machine `/home/james/.ssh/id_rsa`, and you only have the public key `/home/james/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

You should see this:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/james/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```